# Jmeter Illegal character found in host: '/' ISSUE

Tags: api, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I tried to install Jmeter on my colleague computer when I executed http request.He has been showing this error, but I found that there is no such error in my computer. I wonder if anyone has encountered a similar problem?

**My**

[My1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD0GF.png)
[My2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m43VC.png)

---

**Colleague**

[colleague1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cDg7.png)
[colleague2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb0bh.png)

--
error message

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Illegal character found in host: '/'
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:360)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:383)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.getUrl(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: Since your question has obviously been answered you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 4):

This problem occurs when using the http request sampler, putting '/' at the end of the Server Name or Ip textbox. It will work if you delete the '/' character at the end of the host information and add it to path.

[image: this request sampler that works correctly]

Comment: Yes, but my computer can make me feel confused

Comment: Most probably due to different Java/JMeter/OS version(s). If you really want the answer you need to [enable debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) by adding `<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.junit" level="debug" />` line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation), restarting JMeter, re-running your test and sharing *jmeter.log* file somehow.

Answer (score 1):

1. This `www.amazon.com/ref=nav_logo` is not a [valid hostname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hostname.7.html)

   > Valid characters for hostnames are ASCII(7) letters
   >      from a to z, the digits from 0 to 9, and the hyphen (-).  A hostname
   >      may not start with a hyphen.
2. In any case your [URL query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is not correct, it should look like:

   ```
   https://www.amazon.com/?ref=nav_logo
                          ^mind this character
   ```

So correct [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration would be:

[image]

Resulting into the following request observable via [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]

---

Going forward be aware that you can build a JMeter Test Plan using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)

Comment: Thx, I am just curious, why can my computer see the results, others can't?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and it was for simple reason. in the server name/ip address instead giving only the severname/ip address i.e **server1** i had accidentally included the **https://server1** and spend two hours to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Even though I cannot tell you why the test behaves differently on your machine vs that of your colleaugue (I would guess that you probably chose different client implementations in the advanced section of the HTTP Request Sampler), you should definitely consider what part of your URL is:

- Protocol
- Server Name or IP
- Path
- Parameter

and use the corresponding fields in JMeter accordingly.

***Hint: "/ref=nav_logo" is most definitely NOT part of the Server Name.***